# Issue with drawing path over MapKit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have created an application that constantly reads the current user coordinates and store them in a SQLite database.
I have a map that is displayed over the whole screen. 
And now I want to draw a line over the map while the user moves.
I already created all this.
The problem is that I can't make it to be a 'live'. The Overlay is not updating.
This is the logic:
 
In ViewDidLoad I have

```
...
if (nil != self.routeLine) {
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
    }
```

In a function that handle each new coordinates I have:

```
...
NSString* coordinate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", thisLocation.longitude, thisLocation.latitude];
            [self.paths addObject:coordinate];

MKMapPoint northEastPoint;
    MKMapPoint southWestPoint;

    // create a c array of points.
    MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * self.paths.count);

    for(int idx = 0; idx < self.paths.count; idx++)
    {
        // break the string down even further to latitude and longitude fields.
        NSString* currentPointString = [self.paths objectAtIndex:idx];
        NSArray* latLonArr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

        CLLocationDegrees latitude  = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

        // create our coordinate and add it to the correct spot in the array
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);


        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);

        // adjust the bounding box
        // if it is the first point, just use them, since we have nothing to compare to yet.
        if (idx == 0) {
            northEastPoint = point;
            southWestPoint = point;
        }
        else
        {
            if (point.x > northEastPoint.x)
                northEastPoint.x = point.x;
            if(point.y > northEastPoint.y)
                northEastPoint.y = point.y;
            if (point.x < southWestPoint.x)
                southWestPoint.x = point.x;
            if (point.y < southWestPoint.y)
                southWestPoint.y = point.y;
        }

        pointArr[idx] = point;
    }

    // create the polyline based on the array of points.
    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:self.paths.count];

    _routeRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, northEastPoint.x - southWestPoint.x, northEastPoint.y - southWestPoint.y);
    // clear the memory allocated earlier for the points
    free(pointArr);
```

This is viewForOverlay delegate function:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        //if we have not yet created an overlay view for this overlay, create it now.
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;
        }

        overlayView = self.routeLineView;
    }
    return overlayView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, the code calls `addOverlay` with `self.routeLine` which I assume is initially set to the previously-saved coordinates.

The map view adds the `MKPoyline` that `routeLine` points to into its internal list of overlays and draws the overlay.

Then, in the "function that handles each new coordinate", `self.routeLine` is changed to point to a *new* `MKPolyline`.

The reason the overlay view is not updated by the map is because the map view is still using the *original* `MKPolyline` that was passed to it when `addOverlay` was called.

Since `MKPolyline` itself is not mutable (it does not allow one to change the list of points/coordinates after creation), there are two main options:

- Remove the existing overlay and add a new one with the updated coordinates.  This is the simplest option.  After setting `self.routeLine` to a new `MKPolyline`, do the following (*for example*):

  ```
  [self.mapView removeOverlays:mapView.overlays];
  self.routeLineView = nil;
  [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
  ```

  The main drawback to this simple approach is that the overlay will seem to flicker if the updates are done frequently or if the overlay is large or complex.
- The alternative is to create a custom overlay and overlay view that are mutable and enabling you to dynamically refresh the overlay more quickly and smoothly.
  Fortunately, [Apple has provided a sample app called Breadcrumb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`?

[UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)